# How to return a array of json using flink sql

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

I want to return a json that contains an array of pojo.

The sql i am using to emit this is

```
INSERT INTO KAFKA_SINK
SELECT 
       id,
       object_arrayagg('id', unnested_segments_id, 'name', segment_name)                        as segments, 
from SOME_TABLE group by id;
```

here `KAFKA_SINK` is the kafka topic i am writing, to defined as

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS KAFKA_SINK
(
    id                      VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    segments                ARRAY<STRING>,
    PRIMARY KEY (pod, org, id) NOT ENFORCED
) WITH (
    'connector' = 'upsert-kafka',
    'topic' = '${output_topic_name}',
    'properties.bootstrap.servers' = '${sink_kafka_servers}',
    'value.format' = 'json',
    'key.format' = 'json',
    'properties.allow.auto.create.topics' = 'true',
    'properties.num.partitions' = '${sink_properties_num_partitions}',
    'value.json.timestamp-format.standard' = 'ISO-8601',
    'sink.parallelism' = '${sink_parallelism}'
);
```

I have a custom aggregate function `object_arrayagg` defined as

```
package com.some.udf;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;
import org.apache.flink.table.annotation.DataTypeHint;
import org.apache.flink.table.annotation.FunctionHint;
import org.apache.flink.table.api.TableException;
import org.apache.flink.table.api.dataview.ListView;
import org.apache.flink.table.functions.AggregateFunction;
import org.apache.flink.types.Row;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

public class ObjectArrayAggregationsFunction extends AggregateFunction<List<String>, ObjectArrayAggregationsFunction.Accumulator> {

    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = new JsonFactory();
    private static final ObjectMapper MAPPER =
            new ObjectMapper(JSON_FACTORY)
                    .configure(SerializationFeature.ORDER_MAP_ENTRIES_BY_KEYS, true);

    @Override
    public Accumulator createAccumulator() {
        return new Accumulator();
    }

    public void resetAccumulator(Accumulator acc) {
        acc.listView.clear();
    }

    public void accumulate(Accumulator accumulator, String... strings) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("accu strings : " + Arrays.toString(strings));

        String[] clone = strings.clone();
        accumulator.listView.add(String.join(",", clone));

    }

    @Override
    public List<String> getValue(Accumulator accumulator) {

        List<String> listout = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            for (final String item : accumulator.listView.get()) {
                String[] split = item.split(",");
                ObjectNode objectNode = MAPPER.createObjectNode();
                for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i += 2) {
                    String key = split[i];
                    String value = split[i + 1];
                    objectNode.put(key, value);
                }
                listout.add(MAPPER.writeValueAsString(objectNode));

            }
            System.out.println("listout " + listout);
            return listout;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new TableException("The accumulator state could not be serialized.", e);
        }

    }

    public void retract(Accumulator acc, String... strings) throws Exception {
        String[] clone = strings.clone();
        acc.listView.remove(String.join(",", clone));
    }

    public void merge(Accumulator acc, Iterable<Accumulator> others) throws Exception {
        for (final Accumulator other : others) {
            acc.listView.addAll(other.listView.getList());
        }
    }

    public static class Accumulator {
        public ListView<String> listView = new ListView<>();

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
            Accumulator that = (Accumulator) o;
            return Objects.equals(listView, that.listView);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hash(listView);
        }
    }
}
```

With all this, the output i am getting is when i run a insert into statement.

```
{
  "id": "role-id-test-5",
  "segmentsUpdated": [
    "{\"id\":\"seg-id-3\",\"name\":\"segment-name-1\"}",
    "{\"id\":\"seg-id-1\",\"name\":\"segment-name-1\"}",
    "{\"id\":\"seg-id-4\",\"name\":\"segment-name-4\"}"
  ]
}
```

The element in the `segmentsUpdated` array are string, how to have this as json like here

```
{
  "id": "role-id-test-5",
  "segmentsUpdated": [
    {\"id\":\"seg-id-3\",\"name\":\"segment-name-1\"},
    {\"id\":\"seg-id-1\",\"name\":\"segment-name-1\"},
    {\"id\":\"seg-id-4\",\"name\":\"segment-name-4\"}
  ]
}
```